# Extra custom-id besides (and consistent with) id

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I would like an "uuid" (not really, but something I can derive from the id using a custom function/SHA/uuid or similar) stored along the id in my table, when the row is created.

It should then never be changed, so that knowing the "uuid" always lets me find the correct row (I have some scripts etc. that are neither ruby nor active_record, that operate on tables with id-ranges that clash with my active-record table)

I assume I can do something like:

```
:after_create {self.uuid = custom_func(self.id); self.save}
```

to have it created, but that does not ensure that uuid is never changed later....

I need the normal id for my activerecord-stuff, and the "uuid" for external scripts, so I am not looking to replace the normal auto_increment id with a uuid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SecureRandom`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html) to generate either a real UUID or a custom token with the size and the characters you want.

```
before_save :generate_uuid_if_blank

def generate_uuid_if_blank
  self.uuid ||= SecureRandom.uuid
end

def generate_token_if_blank
  self.token ||= SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(12)
end
```

Comment: How does this make sure uuid never changes?

Comment: Once it is set (no nil), it will never changed unless a code change it on purpose. The `||=` will set it only if is nil. I did because you should populate even though legacy objects that does not have uuid yet.

Comment: "a code change it on purpose" was what I wanted to avoid :)

Comment: If I want the "uuid" to be derived from the database id I cannot use before_save since it does not have an id  before_save.